# MySQL: Insert into new table and put 4 different columns as 4 different rows in new table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get `id` `tel` `tel2` `tel3` `tel4` from table `companies`, and put them in a new phone number table called `company_phonenumbers` by adding a new row for each phone number. The columns there are `id` `company_id` `phonenumber`. I just don't know how to get this result.

Companies:

```
| id | tel             | tel2            | tel3            | tel4            |
| -- | --------------- | --------------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| 1  | 123456789       | 987654321       | 246892356       | NULL            |
| 2  | 481857164       | 481857164       |                 |                 |
```

Expected result in `company_phonenumbers`:

```
| id | company_id  | phonenumber | 
| -- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1  | 1           | 123456789   | 
| 2  | 1           | 987654321   |
| 3  | 1           | 246892356   |
| 4  | 2           | 481857164   |
| 5  | 2           | 481857164   |
```

Comment: ```INSERT INTO dst SELECT id, tel1 FROM src UNION ALL SELECT id, tel2 FROM src UNION ALL ...```

Comment: Hooray! Someone is taking our advice and normalizing their data.